# Use of unresolved identifier 'RLMRealmPathForFile'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

I upgraded realm to 0.96.2 and cocoa pods to 0.39.0 but now my build will not compile. It previously worked flawlessly. The build fails on RealmConfiguration.swift, line 58, with the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'RLMRealmPathForFile'." I've debugged this for hours to no resolve. Any thoughts?

Using Xcode 7.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you tried already to clean your build folder? (⌥⇧⌘K)

Comment: Yes, multiple times, before/after pod update and pod install too.

Comment: Can you nuke your integration by `rm -rf Pods` or even better [`pod deintegrate`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) and re-install from scratch again?

Comment: Not sure exactly what fixed it, but I did the pod reintegrate and pod install and then mad sure that I was incrementing the schema version in the app delegate. I then started receiving a bad access error, which I believe was because of a dynamic lazy var in a realm object I had. I shifted some code to make it a normal dynamic var (instead of lazy), which removed the bad access error. My app now builds and runs, but I cannot archive it. I receive a "No such module Google" when I try to archive it. Not sure now, but thanks for your help on the previous issue.

Comment: Which pod from Google are you using? It may not work with the frameworks integration mode. (`use_frameworks!`) I'd recommend of taking a look into the [CocoaPods repo issues](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues) and see whether that came up before and if not I'd recommend to create a separate question on StackOverflow for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to reset the integration done by CocoaPods by either just deleting the Pods directory via `rm -rf Pods` or even better using [`pod deintegrate`](https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) and re-install from scratch again.

Comment: I have installed Realm as a Swift package, so this can't be the case I guess

Comment: @brainray: If you're still having troubles, could you ask a new question where you lay out how you integrate, which versions are involved etc.? This question was asked more than a year ago about Realm 0.96.2, Xcode 7.1, and CocoaPods 0.39. For all of these there are new major versions, that means also a lot has changed.